# EF Code First renaming of properties in generated POCO classes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-generation, t4

I'm using Entity Data Model Wizard(Code First From Database) to generate the dbcontext and POCO Classes. Unfortunately I'm running on a very old database and all the database columns have lowercase names, frequently with underscores and look like garbage in C#. It'd be really nice with the ~100 tables we have if the code generator would put the attribute [Column("column_name")] above everything that wasn't capitalized in the database or if there was an easy way to tell visual studio to look at a file and add that attribute for all lowercase properties that don't already have it(or even just all properties period).

I've looked at some T4 stuff, reverse poco generator, etc. But it seemed nearly as time consuming to get it up and running as manually renaming the properties. Is the source for the (Entity Data Model Wizard) code that runs when you select "ADO.NET Entity Data Model" in the VS Add New Item window available anywhere so I can start with something that is already working?

Or does someone know of an epic find/replace that will take

```
public string n_addr1 { get; set; }
```

and give

```
[Column("n_addr1")]
public string N_addr1 { get; set; }
```

without knowing what n_addr1 is called, meaning it would have to match on public string and/or {get; set;}

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio is this?  The find / replace regex syntax differs from version to version.  Also, it may not be possible to change the case.  It might be easier to actually write a quick console application to run through your source files and make the changes.

Comment: VS 2015 Pro 14.0.24720.00 Update 1 - I think you're right, a console application may be the way to go.

Comment: This is as close as I can get with find & replace.  Find: `public string {[A-Za-z_\d]+}`  Replace:`[Column("$1")] public string $1`.  It doesn't fix up the case, and it doesn't give a carriage return.  Good luck with the console app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something similar and I'm going to post the code I used to find the "name" of the class.  I edited so that it works with a fileName you pass.  Tested on one of my classes and this is working.

```
var fileName = @"YOUR FILE NAME";
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName))
{
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        var line = sr.ReadLine();
        var match = Regex.Match(line, @"{\s?get;\s?set;\s?}");
        if (match.Success)
        {
            var split = Regex.Split(line, @"{\s?get;\s?set;\s?}");
            var declaration = split[0].Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            var last = declaration.Count();
            var name = declaration[last - 1];
            builder.AppendLine(string.Format("[Column(\"{0}\")]", name));
        }
        builder.AppendLine(line);
    }
}
```